# Selenium script doesnot wait long enough for the time defined in explicit wait

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automated-tests, browser-automation

I am writing a selenium script using TestNG framework. i have defined the explicit wait as 20 seconds before selenium throws the NoSuchElement exception. but script does not wait for the 20 second during the execution and throws exception in 41 milliseconds.
i want this script to wait(using explicit wait only) or search for web element for 20 seconds before throwing any exception.

Below is the script followed by the execution result.

```
public class para {
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
void InvokeFF() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            "C:/Users/Vinay/workspace_n/EGuru/drivers/geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    // driver.get("http://seleniumpractise.blogspot.in/2016/08/bootstrap-dropdown-example-for-selenium.html");
    System.out.println("Firefox invoked");
    System.out.println("Firefox thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());

}

@Test
void Auto() throws Exception {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/Vinay/Desktop/Upload1.html");
    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='1']"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
            .xpath(".//*[@id='1']")));
    elem.click();
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Vinay\\Desktop\\AutoUpload.exe");
}
```

> ---
>
> Firefox invoked Firefox thread:1 Execution Started [Utils] Attempting
>   to create C:\Users\Vinay\workspace_n\EGuru\test-output\Default
>   suite\Default test.xml [Utils]   Directory
>   C:\Users\Vinay\workspace_n\EGuru\test-output\Default suite exists:
>   true FAILED: Auto org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable
>   to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='1']"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 41 milliseconds For documentation on this
>   error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
>   System info: host: 'Vinay-PC', ip: '192.168.1.2', os.name: 'Windows
>   7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   databaseEnabled=true, version=45.0.2, platform=WINDOWS,
>   nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   d40fc001-400c-473b-8213-078e641b3c7f
>   *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//*[@id='1']}  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='1']"));
> wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
>         .xpath(".//*[@id='1']")));
> ```

The above two lines need to be reversed in order.  You are attempting to get the element without a wait, then telling the webdriver to wait until it's there.